# Azure Monitor Agent Custom Logs not working

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-arc

I added my laptop to Azure ARC and installed the Azure Monitoring Agent. It all works great and I get the heartbeats.

**I tried 2 methods for adding a custom log, both of which does not work**

**Method 1**

When adding a custom log though is where things fall apart for me, not sure if I am missing something. I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-collection-text-log?tabs=portal

I created the Data Collection Rule and added a resource (my laptop)
[Screenshot of DCR Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDHfu.png)

I then created a custom text logs data sources and the table is the one that I created with Powershell according to the tutorial.
[Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gfGk.png)

The destination of this data source is the log analytics workspace that contains this table
[Data Source Destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYZfe.png)

The table does not seem to contain any data collection rules
[No data collection rules associated with table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/941KQ.png)

I left everything for about 30 minutes and checked for data, but no data was imported. The log files contain only 2 columns to match with the table format and keep it simple for now. Here is an example:
`2023-03-29T12:19:52.983Z myclass.py`

**Method 2**

I created a new Custom Log (DRC based) table in the same Log Analytics Workspace. I then create a new Data Collection Rule (I also tried pointing this new table to an existing Data Collection Rule).

In both cases a weird entry like this one gets created. When I then add a Custom Text Log Data source so that I can tell the DCR where to find the logs, this weird entry gets removed
[Weird Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Foxh1.png)

When I check the table, there are still no DCR associated with the table.

Logic tells me when you right click the table and click on "Manage Table" a DCR should be associated with the table, otherwise where will the DCR know to which table in the Log Analytics Workspace to send the custom text log data to?

Or I am missing something probably very obvious and that is why I cannot get it to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps and able to create custom logs.

Create a new workspace from log analytics by choosing your subscription and resource group.

[image]

Choose the same region of the resource group to workspace.

Choose custom logs.

[image]

Add a sample log file.

[image]

[image]

After this you need to create a [Data Collection Endpoint from Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-endpoint-overview?tabs=portal).

[image]

Make sure the region is same as for the resource group.

After that you need to create a [Data Collection Rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-collection-rule-overview) with a `Resource` and `Data source`.

[image]

[Query the logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-overview) from the log analytics using KQL.

[image]

> Check if any records have been collected for your custom log table by running the below query in Log Analytics with difference in time range.

```
<YourCustomLog>_CL
| where TimeGenerated > ago(48h)
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

> And also verify that Azure Monitor agent is communicating properly by running the below query in Log Analytics to check if there are any records in the Heartbeat table.

```
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > ago(24h)
| where Computer has "<computer name>"
| project TimeGenerated, Category, Version
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

Also verify that the `filePatterns` element specifies the path to the log file to collect from the agent computer.

For further information refer to this [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Vl1BIGXHV0).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately I do not have "Custom Logs" under my Settings blade in the Log Analytics Workspace. I have "Legacy Custom Logs" which I don't want to use as support seems to be ending in 2024, so I have to the use DCR table methods.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays "Custom Logs" are to be found under "Tables", then "+ Create"
[image]